Is it impossible to retrieve SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() in OncePerRequestFilter?
Problem:
You are attempting to authenticate a user within the demo-admin module using the following code:
Authentication authentication = null;
try {
    authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password));
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.error(e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

Later, you are trying to retrieve this authentication in the JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter (which extends OncePerRequestFilter) within the demo-framework module using the following code:
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

However, getAuthentication() returns null, which indicates that the authentication context is not properly set when JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter is executed.
I'm wondering why I can't get the identity information in JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter

There should be no problem in getting it in the filter but you have to make sure it executes after the Spring Security chain. I suspect you are not properly registering it, executing it before the security chain leading to nothing be set.
